# Access SQL with forms showing wrong result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am really new to Access and I'm overwhelmed with this single query.

I have one table and a form based on this table.
In this form the user can select different criteria to filter the result.
But the Problem is with the fields `[Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_von_Box]`  and `[Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_Bis_Box]`
its 'date from' and 'date to', the user should be able to see the records within these dates. But if they are empty then all the records should be shown regardless if they are empty or filled with regards to the other criteria in the form like `"((Vergabeumfang.V_Einkauf_Name)"` but when I leave it empty the query shows only the records where `Vergabeumfang.[500_Plan]` is empty and not all.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
SELECT Vergabeumfang.V_Commodity_Nr, Vergabeumfang.Einkaufsvorgang_Id, Vergabeumfang.Produktlinien, Vergabeumfang.Entscheidungsmethode, Vergabeumfang.Vergabestatus, Vergabeumfang.V_Einkauf_Name, Vergabeumfang.V_QMT_Name, Vergabeumfang.V_Logistik_Name, Vergabeumfang.V_Entwicklung_Name, Vergabeumfang.Einkaufsvorgang, Vergabeumfang.[500_Plan], *
FROM Vergabeumfang
WHERE (((Vergabeumfang.V_Commodity_Nr) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Commoduity_Nr_Box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.Einkaufsvorgang_Id) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Vorgang ID box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.Produktlinien) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Produktlinien Box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.Entscheidungsmethode) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Entscheidungsmethode_Box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.Vergabestatus) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Vergabestatus_Box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.V_Einkauf_Name) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Einkauf_Name_Box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.V_QMT_Name) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![QMT_Name_Box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.V_Logistik_Name) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Logistik_Name_Box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.V_Entwicklung_Name) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Entwicklung_Name_Box] & "*") AND ((Vergabeumfang.Einkaufsvorgang) Like "*" & [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![Einkaufvorgang_Box] & "*") 


AND (IIF( [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_bis_Box] Is Null and [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_von_Box] Is Null ,                (Vergabeumfang.[500_Plan]) Is Null ,
          (Vergabeumfang.[500_Plan]) Between [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_von_Box] And [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_bis_Box]
          )   )


);
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The clause `(Vergabeumfang.[500_Plan]) Is Null` from your query is what is restricting your results to only those records where `Vergabeumfang.[500_Plan]` is empty.

The quickest way to fix this is to change the clause `(Vergabeumfang.[500_Plan]) Is Null` to `True`:

```
AND (IIF( [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_bis_Box] Is Null and 
          [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_von_Box] Is Null ,
          True ,
          (Vergabeumfang.[500_Plan]) Between 
              [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_von_Box] And 
              [Forms]![Vergabeumfang]![500_Termin_bis_Box]
          )   )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply mwolfe02 I just tried what you suggested but still seeing the same results. It is only showing the records where the "500_Termin_von_Box" is not empty